# Imprimir un mensaje sólo una vez

Tags: python, bucles

Tengo este bucle que me busca los números repetidos entre dos listas:

```
list_one = [1,2,3]
list_two = [0,0,0]
rep = []
for x in list_one:
    if x in list_two:
        rep.append(x)
        print(rep)
    else:
        if x not in list_two:
            print('No hubo repetidos')
```

Este es el output:

```
No hubo repetidos
No hubo repetidos
No hubo repetidos
```

La cuestión es que quiero que sólo me salga una vez el mensaje de 'No hubo repetidos', ¿alguien sabe cómo hacerlo?

Answer (score 2):

Te enredastes con la lógica; lo podemos replantear así:

```
list_one = [1,2,3]
list_two = [1,0,0]
rep = []
for x in list_one:
    if x in list_two:
        rep.append(x)

if rep:
    print(rep)
else:
    print('No hubo repetidos')
```

Em `rep` guardas los repetidos que encuentran. Por tanto, si al salir del `for` la lista `rep` tiene elementos, los imprimes, y si no, dejas el mensaje.

Recuerda que en Python una lista vacía (evaluada en una expresión lógica) es `False`. Una lista con uno o más elementos es `True`.

#### Demo

Probe con la lista original (imprime el mensaje) y con esta otra, que si tiene repetidos:

```
list_one = [1,2,3]
list_two = [1,0,0]
rep = []
for x in list_one:
    if x in list_two:
        rep.append(x)

if rep:
    print(rep)
else:
    print('No hubo repetidos')
```

produce:

```
[1]

Process finished with exit code 0
```